# How do I store a picture in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, database, blob

I want to store an image in a MySQL database. I have created a table with a BLOB datatype, but now how do I store the image in this table?

Comment: Better option could be store the physical path of the image in the DB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to check out the following example:

From [**java2s.com: Insert picture to MySQL**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InsertpicturetoMySQL.htm):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class InsertPictureToMySql {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName", "root", "root");
    String INSERT_PICTURE = "INSERT INTO MyPictures (photo) VALUES (?)";

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);
      File file = new File("/tmp/photo.png");
      fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_PICTURE);
      ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());
      ps.executeUpdate();
      conn.commit();
    } finally {
      ps.close();
      fis.close();
    }
  }
}
```

MySQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE MyPictures (
   photo  BLOB
);
```

If the image is located on your MySQL server host, you could use the [**`LOAD_FILE()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) command from a MySQL client:

```
INSERT INTO MyPictures (photo) VALUES(LOAD_FILE('/tmp/photo.png'));
```

Comment: Can we insert the image using simple query language?

Comment: Yes, you may want to try using the `LOAD_FILE()` function: `INSERT INTO mytbl (image_data) VALUES(LOAD_FILE('/tmp/myimage.png'));` (http://www.freeopenbook.com/mysqlcookbook/mysqlckbk-CHP-17-SECT-7.html)

Comment: Karthik, what is not working?... The `LOAD_FILE()` method? If yes, make sure that the file is readable by mysql, and also make sure that your mysql user has the `FILE` privilege.

Comment: To grant the `FILE` privilege, log-in as root and execute `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'mysql_user'@'localhost'`.

Comment: @Daniel : how to check whether my MySQl has File privilege, if i am not having it how to give the privilege and  also how to store the image file in server host?

Comment: @Hari: To check the privileges of the current user, log-in with your user in mysql `mysql -h localhost -u user -p` and execute `SHOW GRANTS;`. To grant the `FILE` privilege, please check my previous comment.

Comment: @Daniel : how to put the image file into the server host?

Comment: @Hari: To put the image on the server host, you will have to upload it yourself (or through a script) on your server's file system. In fact, this is not the ideal method to insert images from a web page, since the uploading to the file system is useless.

Comment: @Daniel : so is it better to add a image into server rather than a adding it into the database right......

Comment: @Karthik: There is an issue on the MySQL bug-tracker http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38403, which is reporting the same behaviour that you are experiencing. Apparently one user solved it by stopping apparmor (which is a security service
like selinux).

Comment: @Hari: You may want to check out this Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/

Comment: @Daniel :ya thanks .. i saw the same post before coming to this one... i thought this post is also having some similarities to that one and also it that one no one told how to insert a image through a query as u have mentioned...

Comment: @Hari: It doesn't look like the question or any of the answers were down-voted :)

Comment: @Daniel :actually the number of up votes was 5 before...and now its 4..just wanted to know that whether any other posible answer is also there...

Answer (score 5):

read the content of the file (BINARY)
and insert it in insert \ update MYSQL query

a lot of example in google :

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InsertpicturetoMySQL.htm

http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/save_image.shtml

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1278882