# how can i store image in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to know how can store image in mysql db and retrieve it when i need to it.

I want to use image with java and netbeans.

Comment: You don't want to do it...any other solution is most likely better suited then this. Anyway, you're looking for the `BLOB` field and...what language were you using again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I store a picture in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939162/how-do-i-store-a-picture-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at BLOBS

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Answer (score 0):

May be late But I just found way to do that.

Way 1: Get image from user and rename with the id (Pref. Primary key) and in Your public_html create folder for images. Set proper permissions for that folder. and save image in that folder and the url of that image will be stored DB column . Like

https://www.example.com/images/user1.png do in that style.

Way 2: use other things to rename that image like user's email,username etc

way 3: In above 2 cases it may happen that other users,hackers may try to download images by using IDs,emails etc. That's why , another way you can do is you can generate a hash for profile and check if the hash already exists in column if exits then generate another one. Likely I don't think there is possibility of generating similar hashes.but you may check to avoid error in future. and now rename image using that generated hash.

You may also reduce size of that link column using only storing generated hash and in your app declare some variables and achieve

https://www.example.com/images/generated_hash.png

here the url will be same in all columns excluding that hash key. you may only store that hashes.

Hope it will help